# How to pass multiple params to the root route in Angular

Tags: angular

For other path 'test', I can use http://localhost/#/test;param1=a;param2=b
But for root path '', I can't use http://localhost/#/;param1=a;param2=b

Anyone helps?

Comment: unable to understand the meaning of root route path! Can you please explain?

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DanmakuListComponent},
  {path: 'test', component: TestComponent}
];

Comment: I mean the path = ''. Empty string.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Could you please help?

Comment: what about empty string? Do you need to replace it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it like this:

In html pass an json object or array, and retrieve it if you need in onInit hook.

So it will require only one param, which can hold many values.

```js
   ngOnInit() {
      this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.data = JSON.parse(params.yourParam);
      });
   }
```

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/']"
       [queryParams]="{yourParam:yourDataInJsonFormat | json }">
       CLick here
    </a>
```

Comment: Thank you. Query params help.